# How to setup Adobe Premiere Pro CC to edit Interview type videos for YouTube

Tags: premiere, editing, youtube

## Context:

- I have Adobe Premiere Pro CC 2017
- I am recording interviews with Ecamm recorder for Skype in 480p resolution (size conscious)
- I always record separate files (audio & video) - track 1 and track 2.
- I created a fancy layout image (16:9) in Photoshop which I drop in Premiere and then I adjust the video tracks so they fit in it - the layout has the guest bit bigger than me (they are obviously more important)

I already tried two different configurations of project/export settings:

1. 1280x720 and 24fps - which was blurry - you could watch it but it was straining my eyes (presets were SLR 720p)
2. 4K and 25fps - which was OK (presets were RED Cinema 4K) and surprisingly the size was also comparable, which is a bit confusing.

## Questions:

- What presets do you recommend when creating Premiere project for a YouTube video? I read that YouTube recommends uploading 720p videos, but nothing like that exists in Premiere presets.
- What settings should I use to render the sequence to have good quality but acceptable file size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What presets do you recommend when creating Premiere project for a YouTube video? I read that YouTube recommends uploading 720p videos, but nothing like that exists in Premiere presets.**

Any preset works as long as your export settings correspond to what YouTube can ingest.

By the way, 720p presets exist in Premiere, for most codecs.
Here's a screen capture for the DNxHD codec:

[image]

**What settings should I use to render the sequence to have good quality but acceptable file size?**

For a 720p file, make sure your data rate is no smaller than 5 Mbps.

For a 1080p file, make sure your data rate is no smaller than 10 Mbps.

Codec: H264.

Field order: progressive usually (depending on your raw footage).

Aspect: square pixel usually (depending on your raw footage).

Audio: AAC, 4100Hz, Maximum Bitrate.

Maximum render quality.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the recommended encoding settings from [YouTube help](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1722171?hl=en)

I am puzzled why you are using a layout image that you drop in Premiere? You should read through [Adobe's Help page](https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/using/creating-changing-sequences.html#create_a_sequence) about creating sequences. That has good information that should help you out.

For myself, I usually shoot in h.264 Video codec, 4K resolution, and for an interview style video, I would probably choose 30fps (frames per second).